# In Xcode, how to clean only one project in workspace

Tags: xcode, workspace

Often Xcode build become messy, so I frequently use `Clean` and re-`Build` my project. The project depends on several open source projects, which is managed by cocoapod.

The problem is that when I use `Clean` <kbd>⇧⌘K</kbd>, the entire workspace is cleaned, so all of the cocoapod-dependencies are rebuilt, which takes most of the build time. But in most of the case, I just want only my own project is cleaned. How do I do this?

Comment: I don't think that you can clean only project within workspace. You can clean whole workspace.

Comment: That's bad news... :-(

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Exclude Pods when cleaning Xcode 9 project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48564548/exclude-pods-when-cleaning-xcode-9-project)

Answer (score 0):

Go to Edit Scheme

[image: Edit Scheme]

Then click **Build** and untick the **Find Implicit Dependencies**

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work for Xcode 10. `Clean` still removes all.