# Exclude Pods when cleaning Xcode 9 project

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods, xcode9

I am wondering if there is a way to exclude your Pods in a Swift 4, Xcode 9 project when performing a *Product -> Clean* operation.

In rare cases when I try to build I get errors like

> file too small for architecture x86_64

Easiest way to fix this is doing a full clean, according to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14034048/xcode-linker-error-file-too-small-for-architecture-x86-64).

This works, but when I have a lot of Pods included in my project, cleaning and rebuilding takes forever. Therefore the question if the Pods can be excluded from being cleaned to save some time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Menu: Product->Scheme->Manage Schemas (way at bottom)

Choose your product target and then click the "Edit..." button at the bottom left.

Select "Build" from left section

Then uncheck the "Find Implicit dependencies" checkbox in the top section.

Comment: It works, but every time you _archive_ your project you _have to_ check it back. Any workarounds for this?

Comment: Also, it doesn't work for Xcode 10